# Javascript memory heap issue on permutating two big array in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, object

```
var array1=[{
                product_code:"test1",
                series:"11w"
            },
            {
                product_code:"test2",
                series:"12w"
            },
            {
                product_code:"test3",
                series:"13w"
            },
            {
                product_code:"test4",
                series:"14w"
            },
            {
                product_code:"test5",
                series:"15w"
            },
            {
                product_code:"test6",
                series:"16w"
            }];

    var array2=[{
                    housing_code:"last_test1",
                    petrize:"swa1"
                },
                {
                    housing_code:"last_test2",
                    petrize:"swa2"
                },
                {
                    housing_code:"last_test3",
                    petrize:"swa3"
                }]
```

My Code:

```
        var finalarray=[];
        array1.map((key1,i1)=>{
            array2.map((key2,i2)=>{
                key1['housing_code']=key2.housing_code;
                key1['petrize']=key2.petrize;
                console.log(key1)
                var sw=JSON.stringify(key1);
                finalarray.push(JSON.parse(sw));
            });


        });
```

This two arrays is just an example.
But first array has more than 4500 objects. 
I have to permutate both array(4500*86) in nodejs.
The finalarray gives more than 200 000 records .
I have 4GB RAM space
I tried node --max-old-space-size=3300 server.js, But it may cause my system hang
I also tried npm increase-memory-limit .

Comment: that being said I would look into trying to use sets instead of arrays as long as you don't have duplicate values. I'm pretty sure they are more performant. Or else you could get a digital ocean server to perform this operation quite cheaply